# Generate partial Disk Images

Tags: windows, hard-disk, disk-image

I have a external HDD that

- produces random read failures (and it would after that show errors for all subsequent read access until I switch it off/on again)
- S.M.A.R.T information shows that the number of corrupted sectors is increasing (and I should replace the HDD with a new one)

Now my problem is that I want to generate one good RAW image `.img` file from this HDD and since my HDD is generating random "read sector failures" I want to find a program that is able to generate partial RAW disk images (that I can concatenate later to one complete good image).

I've tried so far:

1. [Acronis True Image 2017](https://www.acronis.com/de-de/personal/computer-backup/) (commercial version)

   - This allows generating images (also split into e.g. 100 GB packages)
   - But it won't allow me to stop/continue after a read failure (and a powercycle of the HDD)
   - I can just retry (doesn't help) or ignore every "sector read failure" afterwards
   - Next time it would start from sector 0 again (so I never get more then the first 30-40% of the disk data)
2. [HDD Raw Copy Tool](http://hddguru.com/software/HDD-Raw-Copy-Tool/)

   - It advertises "low-level" copying, but the results were the same as above

Just from looking at command line tools like [Linux's `dd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)) or some [clones for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/windd/) it's probably doable, but I would prefer something with a GUI on Windows which gives me some sort of visual control/overview of what I'm doing.

Alternatively I'm looking for a tool that does allow to "continue" after a failed disk-imaging at the position of failure (like with a download in my browser after I lost contact with the server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search and some trial and error e.g. with `dd` I ended up booting Linux for USB memory stick and using [`ddrescue`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) command line tool.

For my case I was paricualry interested in [an example from the manuals](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Examples):

> Example 5: While rescuing a partition in /dev/sda1 to the file hdimage, /dev/sda1 stops responding and begins returning read errors, causing ddrescue to mark the rest of the partition as non-scraped.
>
> ```
> ddrescue -f -n /dev/sda1 hdimage mapfile     <-- /dev/sda1 fails here
>   (restart /dev/sda or reboot computer)
> ddrescue -f -n -A -i<pos> /dev/sda1 hdimage mapfile
>   (if /dev/sda1 fails again, restart /dev/sda or reboot computer and
>    then repeat the above command as many times as needed until it
>    succeeds. <pos> is the position of the last block marked as
>    non-scraped in the mapfile)
> ddrescue -d -f -r3 /dev/sda1 hdimage mapfile
> ```

I've just replaced the - for files - unnecessary option `-f` (force overwrite) with `-v` (verbose) option.

My mapfile after serveral repeated second steps (and about 6 hours for 1TB later) looked like this:

```
# Rescue Logfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.19
# Command line: ddrescue -v -n -A -i0xCCF9C10000 /dev/sda2 hdimage mapfile
# Start time:   ...
# Current time: ...
# Finished
# current_pos  current_status
0xE8D8BF0000     +
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x59FAA45000  +
0x59FAA45000  0x0001B000  ?
0x59FAA60000  0x02B6A000  +
0x59FD5CA000  0x00016000  ?
0x59FD5E0000  0x5D600000  +
0x5A5ABE0000  0x00020000  ?
0x5A5AC00000  0x0CDB2000  +
0x5A679B2000  0x0001E000  ?
0x5A679D0000  0x2EDA9B000  +
0x5D5546B000  0x00015000  ?
0x5D55480000  0x3B5AB1000  +
0x610AF31000  0x6BE3F000  ?
0x6176D70000  0x8761E90000  +
```

And after the last call to retry and fill the gaps I ended up with just one none-recoverable sector and the following mapfile:

```
# Rescue Logfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.19
# Command line: ddrescue -d -v -r3 /dev/sda2 hdimage mapfile
# Start time:   ...
# Current time: ...
# Finished
# current_pos  current_status
0x59FD5CA400     +
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x59FD5CA400  +
0x59FD5CA400  0x00000200  -
0x59FD5CA600  0x8EDB635A00  +
```

**References**

- [SuperUser: Recovering data from a hard drive which disappears from /dev upon reading data in a bad block](https://superuser.com/questions/1137755/recovering-data-from-a-hard-drive-which-disappears-from-dev-upon-reading-data-i)
- [Technibble: Guide to Using DDRescue to Recover Data](https://www.technibble.com/guide-using-ddrescue-recover-data/)